# Array index out of bounds exception: 100

Tags: processing

```
    //----------------------------------------------\\
float x = 300;

float y = 300;

float direction = 0;

float increment = 1;

float speed = 5;

boolean toggle = true; // - For spaceship reversal

float wormX = random(0, 600); // - For wormHole v

float wormY = random(0, 600);

float wormGrowth = 0;

boolean growthSwitch = true; // - for wormHole ^

float[] starXpos = new float[100]; //starsRandom

float[] starYpos = new float[100]; //starsRandom

float d = dist(x, y, wormX, wormY);

int score = 0;



//----------------------------------------------\\
//----------------------------------------------\\ Setup

void setup (){

  size (600, 600);

starsP1();

}
//----------------------------------------------\\ Draw

void draw (){

background (0);

  spaceShip();   
  starsP2();
  wormHole ();
  score();
  warpInitial();
  blackHoleAt(100, 40);
  blackHoleAt(400, 500);


}
//----------------------------------------------\\ 
//----------------------------------------------\\ starsRandom
void starsP1(){

  int i = 0;
   while (i < 100){
     starXpos[i] = random(0, width);
     starYpos[i] = random(0, height);
       i = i + 1;
     } 
}

void starsP2(){

  stroke(255);
  strokeWeight(5);

  int i = 0;
  while (i < 100){
  point(starXpos[i], starYpos[i]);
   i = i + 1; 
   } 
    if (key == 'w'){
   starYpos[i] = starYpos[i] + 1;
 } 




}
```

I'm trying to create a form of parallax for the stars in my code. When the user presses w,a,s,d the array of stars should correspond to the direction. I don't understand how this should work as I keep getting this error.

Comment: After the while loop in `starsP2` your `i` variable has the value `100` while maximal possible array element is `99`. When you create `new float[100]` array, it has elements from `0` to `99`.

Comment: How would I change this so that when 'w' is pressed the stars move?

Answer (score 1):

Try formatting your code to better see what's going on:

```
void starsP2(){

  stroke(255);
  strokeWeight(5);

  int i = 0;
  while (i < 100){
     point(starXpos[i], starYpos[i]);
     i = i + 1; 
  }

  if (key == 'w'){
     starYpos[i] = starYpos[i] + 1;
  } 
}
```

Your while loop executes until i == 100. Then after the while loop exits, you use that `i` variable again. Since `i` is 100, and your `starYpos` array only has up to index 99, you get an error.

The fix is to either move that if statement to inside the while loop, or to refactor your code so `i` doesn't go outside the bounds of the array.